# How to fix this security exception.?

Tags: java, jar

I am using this jar: `webcam-capture-0.3.10-RC6.jar`. I use this jar inside my project (in a Java applet), and then I create the jar file for my applet. After that, I sign the jar and use the signed jar file. Unfortunately, I'm getting a security exception and my application is blocking this jar (`webcam-capture-0.3.10-RC6.jar`), and it shows that it's blocking a "potentially unsafe component from being run". My application contains both signed and unsigned code.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Is the jar `webcam-capture-0.3.10-RC6.jar` signed ?

Comment: I got this jar from github site. i don't no whether it is signed or not.

Comment: i will sign this webcam-capture-0.3.10-RC6.jar and i will check whether it is working